# Prerequisites for non-standard analysis

Tags: analysis, nonstandard-analysis

Today my real analysis teacher mentioned the existence of "non-standard analysis" and explained on a very basic level what it studies and it immediately caught my attention. After that he mentioned that it is an advanced subject and that got my wondering: what are the necessary prerequisites to be able to learn non-standard analysis up to an intermediate/advanced level? Is real analysis and a little bit of abstract algebra enough?

Comment: You might require more than the usual set theory than standard real analysis usually requires. Not necessarily  a whole set theory course.

Answer (score 1):

To understand non-standard models, I believe a good place to start would be some set theory and introductory logic. Understanding concepts like languages, formulas, sentences, theory of a model, isomorphisms, elementary equivalence, and more is essential. This along with a good understanding of the compactness theorem (in logic) and ultrafilters should be enough to get you started. The best place to get this content is probably an introductory logic textbook, there are some good open-sourced options available on the web, for example:

https://knightscholar.geneseo.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1005&context=geneseo-authors

Answer (score 1):

No background is needed beyond basic calculus.  One good introductory textbook that presents the necessary background from logic in a self-contained fashion is Goldblatt:

> Goldblatt, Robert.
> Lectures on the hyperreals.
> An introduction to nonstandard analysis. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 188. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1998.

Nonstandard analysis has numerous applications.  For applications in physics, see

> Albeverio, Sergio; Høegh-Krohn, Raphael; Fenstad, Jens Erik; Lindstrøm, Tom Nonstandard methods in stochastic analysis and mathematical physics. Pure and Applied Mathematics, 122. Academic Press, Inc., Orlando, FL, 1986.

For applications in functional analysis, measure and probability theory, stochastic analysis, mathematical economics, and combinatorial game theory, see

> Nonstandard analysis for the working mathematician. Second edition. Edited by Peter A. Loeb and Manfred P. H. Wolff. Springer, Dordrecht, 2015.

Both of these books have hundreds of citations in the mathematical and scientific literature.